# Django urls slug must contain word

Tags: python, regex, django

here is my URL:

```
/jobs-in-new-york
```

here is my **urls.py**

```py
url(r'^account/', include('.account.urls')),
url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'^payment/', include('.payments.urls', namespace='payments')),
url(r'^student/', include('.student.urls')),
url(r'^employer/', include('.employer.urls')),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\/]+)', JobSearchView.as_view(), name='job_search')
```

How can I change this regex `^(?P<slug>[-\w\/]+)` so that if slug contains word **jobs**, it gets matched!

Comment: "Contains" or "starts with"?

Comment: Contains! so it can match `/remote-jobs` as well

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a positive lookahead to assert for `jobs` between word boundaries `\b`

```
^(?=.*\bjobs\b)(?P<slug>[-\w/]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLmCRX/1)

If the pattern could start with a forward slash, you might use

```
^(?P<slug>/?(?:\w+-)*jobs(?:-\w+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<slug>` Names group slug

  - `/?` Match `/` optional `/`
  - (?:\w+-)*` Repeat 0+ times a word character and -
  - `jobs` Match literally
  - `(?:-\w+)*` Repeat 0+ times - and 1+ word characters
  - `)` Close named group slug
- `$` End of string

Note that using this pattern there can be no 2 consecutive `--`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkPa5J/1/)

Comment: I can see the demo but it gives me `ValueError: Non-reversible reg-exp portion: '(?='`

Comment: @VaibhavMule [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570463/django-url-reverse-non-reversible-reg-exp-portion)  has that error as a topic. Can you try the second pattern without the lookahead?

Comment: even second does not work! at it gives, `NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'job_search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'web-designing-development-jobs'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>/(?:\\w+-)*jobs(?:-\\w+)*)$']`

Comment: @VaibhavMule should it start with a `/`? I have updated it for that so it can start with an optional forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
^(?P<slug>[-\w]*jobs[-\w]*)/'
```

- `[-\w]*` matches `-` or any of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, zero or more times
- `jobs` matches `jobs` literally